# Load Magento theme to external file php

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout, theme, frontend

I am using an external PHP file to make a page, how do I load a Magento 2 theme to my external PHP code so that my PHP has the same theme layout as my normal Magento 2 layout page, what I am trying to add is the header and footer to my PHP file.